# Populating array in mathematica

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica, 2d

I have a set of around 500 (x,y,z) real values. Since I will need to bin the values based on their (x,y) coordinates, I stripped the z values and stored in on a seperate list. I am left with only the x,y values; I rescaled and rounded them to index pairs in the range of, 1..100 range.

Now I want to populate an array with the z values in a 100x100 matrix at the particular (x,y) coordinates.

More precisely,

I have a set of values for example : `data = {{2.62399, 0.338057, 2.09629}, {1.8424, 0.135817, 3.21925}, {0.702257,   1.14502, 3.9335}...`

I stripped it of its zvalues and store it in zvalues list:

```
zvalues = {2.09629, 3.21925, 3.9335....
```

I rounded, rescaled and created a new array of indices

```
indices = {{53, 7}, {37, 3}, {14, 23}...
```

I want to create a new 100x100 matrix and place the zvalues on the coordinates corresponding to the indices matrix

For example, in pseudocode

```
For (int i = 1, i < 101, i++){

NewArray(indices[i]) = zvalues[i];
}
```

The first time the loop will run, it should do `NewArray(53,7) = 2.09629`.

I want to know the syntax to loop through the indices array and populate the 2 dimensional 100x100 NewArray with zvalues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to follow your basic approach you need to initialize the array:

```
newArray=Table[,{100},{100}]
```

then in the loop the syntax is:

```
newArray[[indices[[i,1]],indices[[i,2]]]]=zdata[[i]]
```

note the double square brackets for referencing parts of arrays (or lists in Mathematica terminology)

A better approach would be to create a SparseArray, which for one thing would not require pre-initialization, or even knowing the dimensions in advance.

Finally in mathematica you can usually use an object oriented approach, avioding the "do" loop all together:

```
data = {{1.5, 1.1, 1.1}, {2.2, 2.2, 2.2}, {1.01, 2.3, 1.2}};
m1 = Table[, {2}, {2}];
(m1[[Floor[#[[1]]], Floor[#[[2]]]]] = #[[3]]) & /@ data;
m1
m2 = SparseArray[ Floor[#[[1 ;; 2]]] -> #[[3]] & /@ data , Automatic,];
Normal[m2]


{{1.1, 1.2}, {Null, 2.2}}
{{1.1, 1.2}, {Null, 2.2}}
```

Comment: Thanks George. Being a beginner, the SparseArray method is a bit hard for me to implement, but I will definitely try this idea when optimising my codes. Thank you

Comment: @Mun you may wish to consider looking at [mathematica.se], a stackexchange site dedicated to _Mathematica_. Most of the experts have migrated over there.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand why you want to create a new way of indexing your array, this will do what you want :

```
data = {{2.62399, 0.338057, 2.09629}, {1.8424, 0.135817, 3.21925}, {0.702257, 1.14502, 3.9335}};
zvalues = {2.09629, 3.21925, 3.9335};
indices = {{53, 7}, {37, 3}, {14, 23}};

newArray[xIndex_, yIndex_]:=Take[data, Position[indices, {xIndex, yIndex}][[1, 1]]][[1, 3]]

newArray[53, 7]
(* 2.09629 *)
```

Comment: thank you.  I have a set of real (x,y,z) values and I want to bin them based on (x,y) values only. So I stripped it of the zvalues, then used binLists(lists of xy,binbondary-x,binboundary-y). Now I want to average the z values of the corresponding (x,y) points in the bins. That's why I attempted to rescale. But doesn't really work as rescale give same coordinates for some points. Any idea how to bin (x,y,z) based on x,y only and average the z values of corresponding x,y value in each bin. Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `BinCounts`.

Comment: @Mun -- you should post that as a new question.  Also I think it should be poited out here, b.g's solution is not an array at all, but a function. It looks like an array in the sense that newArray[i,j] returns the value you want, but you will not be able to apply built in array operators.